# show database time span value to numeric updown control

Tags: vb.net

I am saving my numericupddown value like this into database

```
Dim value As Date = New Date(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, 0, NumericUpDown1.Value, 0)
Dim valueAsString As String = value.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

..it will save data like `00:05:00`.

I want to fetch corresponding data to my numeric updown control.
I am fetching data using my data reader.then i try to give code like this:

```
 NumericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dr("Timeinterval")).ToString
```

But showing

```
error:Unable to cast object of type `System.TimeSpan` to type `System.IConvertible`.
```

How can I show corresponding data to my numericupdown control?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert 00:05:00 to a decimal, which obviously is wrong. Before saving to database, you changed the value in your updown control to HH:mm:ss format. Now you need to write custom logic to convert 00:05:00 to number like `((HH * 60) + mm + (ss / 60))` before you would be able to convert it back to Decimal.

Comment: my self i resolved this issue:Dim value As TimeSpan = dr("Timeinterval")
                Dim s As String = value.Minutes
                NumericUpDown1.Value = s